# Qlikview document reload fails due to authorization restrictions on SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, qlikview

## The situation

I have created a Qlikview document based on SharePoint 2010 list data. The document is working just fine and I am able to reload data from my desktop, and ready to deploy to our Qlikview server.

## The problem

However, when I run a script *("C:\Program Files (x86)\QlikView\Qv.exe" /r Qlikdoc.qvw)* on the server to reload the document, it returns "Access denied". If I open the document on the server and reloads it returns the same: "Access Denied". If i open the SharePoint site inside Qlikview (File -> Open URL...") logs in with the right credentials and THEN reloads the document it works just fine.

## The question

**How do I store the session from the URL or call the reload function with windows credentials?** (The service user is already an admin on the SharePoint site.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure which credentials you use on the server, I assume that they must be different from your own.

In this case, you could set up a task on the server using Task Scheduler to execute your batch script to reload the QlikView document. If you set the security options to run the script using your "service" account's credentials, then this should reload the QV document using that identity. This is the easiest way to execute it and ensure that the credentials are not stored in plaintext anywhere.

Depending on your network configuration and SharePoint set-up (e.g. if your SharePoint domain is different from the server's), you may also need to add your SharePoint server's domain to your "Local Intranet" sites in Internet Explorer for the service account.

Comment: Thank you for the tip!

I added the SharePoint site to the "Local Intranet" and created a .bat file and made it an action in the Task Scheduler.

Pure one time fix! Thanks